ssh URI functioning and config file
Firstly I would like to give context: I was trying to set my git and my ssh in ubuntu to handle multiple accounts (work, personal-study and personal projects). Following some tutorials, I wrote in my ssh the configuration for each type of connection. The next is the example of the configuration for the work account (inside config file in .ssh/)
Host work.github.com
HostName github.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed_work
User git
IdentitiesOnly yes

From the github repository I got an ssh URI
git@github.com:my_work_username/name_repository.git
I was having trouble making them work together up until I changed the URI provided by github at the moment of adding it as the remote of my local repository. I had to change it to the format:
git@work.github.com:my_work_username/name_repository.git

When using the command git remote add, so it matched the format I had given in the ssh file (in the line of Host). First, I didn't know you could manually change the URI provided by github, secondly, even though I have found sources like this one, I have been having trouble understanding what each part of an ssh URI does, what it refers to and why can I change that part without affecting the connection to my repository. I will thank any information and also sources to study more about server, hosts, will also be appreciated.

work.github.com:my_work_username/name_repository.git should be sufficient. Git only needs to know where to go and the name of the repository once it gets there. ssh takes care of how to get there, using the Host declaration to find all the necessary details for connecting to work.github.com.

To build on @chepner's excellent comment, the work.github.com entry in your ~/.ssh/config file is much like an entry in your phone's contacts app - as long as you refer to work.github.com then the config file will pick up the correct hostname, username, keys, and other settings.

@chepner Thank you. It does work. I just want to clarify a little bit more technically how does the ssh URI works and why is it that I can change that specific part of the URI before de colon. I just figured it out kind of with try and error but don't really get why it works that way.

work.github.com:my_work_username/name_repository is just an abbreviated form of the proper URI ssh://work.githhub.com/my_work_username/name_repository. Either way, ssh looks for a Host entry in its configuration before assuming that the given "host name" (or authority, in URL terms) really is an actual DNS name to look up or an IP address to use.

Basically, you are still using the URI provided by GitHub; you are just changing how ssh constructs that URI from its own configuration and the URI you provide to the git command.

@chepner (I'm pedant and a wet blanket) "ssh constructs that URI" Nope, SSH knows nothing about URIs, it knows hosts, ports and user names. Git parses URIs and passes hosts, ports and user names to SSH.

blanket... too... heavy... to argue :) I'll just pretend I meant "constructs" in the loosest sense possible

(Going to attempt to cobble together a proper answer from all the comments.)

So first, the URI simply provides information about how to reach a given repository. You can provide that information in any way you like, as long as it is equivalent to the URI shown on GitHub.
Not terribly relevant, but worth remembering, is that git@github.com:my_work_username/name_repository.git is an alternate form of the more proper URI ssh://git@github.com/my_work_username/name_repository.git.
The URI provides the following bits of information:

The fact that ssh will be used to connect to GitHub.
The user id git, as whom you will authenticate. (Everyone is git, but git has many, many certificates associated with it, and access to repositories belong to git is determined by which certificate git chose to use to authenticate.)
The host to connect to (github.com)
The path to the repository (my_work_username/name_repository.git)

If ssh had no further configuration to go on, it would parse the URI and do the best it could. But you do provide further configuration, in the form of a block in your .ssh/config file:
Host work.github.com
HostName github.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed_work
User git
IdentitiesOnly yes

This defines an alias, work.github.com, to which you associate a "real" host name, an identity file, a user name, and an instruction to ignore identities from "outside" sources (like ssh-agent; it's not worth going further into the meaning of this option here).
So instead of executing
ssh -i id_ed_work  -o IdentitiesOnly=yes git@github.com:my_work_username/name_repository.git

using the "original" URI,  you use the alias work.github.com to execute the shorter command
ssh work.github.com:my_work_username/name_repository.git

Both commands use the same information provided by the original URI to connect.
